# Why does "If it's ready made, this will get me down! (5)" clue REACH?

Tags: word, wordplay, cryptic-clues

> If it's ready made, this will get me down! (5)

This is from the Metro newspaper cryptic crossword for Dec 14, 2021. I already had R _ A _ H, so the answer was fairly obviously REACH and this was confirmed by Google.

What is the link between the clue and the answer?

Answer (score 6):

[Reach-me-down](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reach-me-down) is a term for ready-made clothing. The word "this" stands in for the answer in the clue, so we need something that can precede "me down" to mean something that's ready-made. REACH is a word that fits that description.

(The "X getting Y" construction would more usually be "Y inside X", but some setters also use it to mean "X next to Y", as here.)